# Express auth middleware not liking the JWT Token it receives from client side React Native AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, express, authentication

I'm working on login authentication with a react native app.  I have login working as someone logs in for the first time through the login form. At this initial login step, I'm sending my JWT web token to my secure routes in my express server as a string and this works fine.  NOTE: I have a middleware setup that my token goes through before my routes will fire completely. 
The problem is when the app refreshes it needs to go to my "local storage".  My express middleware doesn't like the token I'm pulling from my "local storage (I retrieve it through AsyncStorate.getItem('UserToken').  When I look at the item being stored in the header, it seems like it's the exact item I was sending it at the initial login, but I think it's my middleware on the server that doesn't like the value when it's coming from the " local storage" header. Below is my middlware.js code.

I've tried looking at the JWT value being sent in both scenarios, and it seems like it's the exact item being sent to the server in both situations.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    //Get Token from header
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');


    // Check if no token
    if(!token) {

        return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied'})
    }

    //Verify token
    try {

        var decoded = jwt.verify(token, global.gConfig.jwtSecret);

        req.user = decoded.user;
        next();
    }catch(err){
        res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid'});

    }

}
```

This is the function I'm using to retrieve the token from AsyncStorage

```
  export  const getAsyncStorage = async () => {

    try {
       // pulling from header to get x-auth-token here
       Value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Usertoken');

        //setting x-auth-token here
       axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = Value;
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }

  };
```

Comment: Is it the second 401 error that gets thrown?

Comment: No 401 error because a value does come through.  However the value comes back as undefined.  What's being sent to the middlware is the jwt token. Not sure why it would be undefined if what's being sent is just a string value.  From what it looks like it is a string value.

Comment: Hang on, are you saying that `next` is called successfully but that `req.user` comes back as `undefined`?

Comment: Correction.  Yes, the 401 error is going off.  Sorry for that. The code in the try, catch is not firing.

Comment: I logged the req in the middleware and can see there is a header being sent to it, but there is no x-auth-token as a key value being sent.  So, I updated my original question to include my client side code I'm using to retrieve the token from my header.

Comment: Does your client side code throw the error?